# Alarm not triggering according to time properly after rebooting

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am using AlramManager to setAlarm using Following method:

```
    public static void scheduleAlarmReceiverOnce(Context context,String did,long time) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, pendingIntent);
}
```

Which i m calling here

```
        Utils.scheduleAlarmReceiverOnce(this, did,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+30000);
```

Its working fine means the alarm is getting exactly at time in my broadcast where i m displaying a toast displayed exactly at 30 seconds.
My problem is when i reboot or restard i m caluculating and substracting the wasted time and scheduling alarm again but with the left time..ON my boot reciever i am starting my service again where alarm is rescheduled.

```
            Utils.scheduleAlarmReceiverOnce(this, did,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+leftime);
```

Whwre lefttime i m getting correctly..exactly around 17000 or 20000 i,e; around 20 seconds 
But my alarm triggers instantly without waiting for 20 seconds..

Help plz..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okk i got the answer ...Logic was correct it was just my date substraction was passing a negative value of long which i was trying to add to Calendar.getInstance().getCurrentTimeMillis...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is store time in Sharedprefernce / Database which you set in alarm and set that time again when you reboot your device.

So your alarm invoked at that exact time you set before reboot.

Try with this in your current code.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class),0);
```

Comment: i m setting the alarm again as u can see...even the caluculation is correct...but its not triggering at tthat time but is instant..as soon as i set the alarm..

Comment: its still the same...its just not waiting for the time set...just triggering instantly